# getDocumentsDirectory Swift5 alternative

Tags: ios, swift3, swift5

There is an error from  `Swift 3.0` at `Swift 5.0`

[image]

The code:

```
//Create audio file name URL
let audioFilename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("audioRecording.m4a")

//Create the audio recording, and assign ourselves as the delegate
audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioFilename, settings: settings)
```

[image]

As I see it should be something like this:

```
   func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL
    {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
        return documentsDirectory
    }
```

Is it correct? Or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use following code:

```
func getDocumentsDirectory() throws -> URL {
     return try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
}
```

do not forget to handle exception case,

```
try {
   let documents = try? getDocumentsDirectory()
   ...
} catch let error {
   print("something went wrong: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: This is one of the rare cases where `try!` can be used unhesitating because it's guaranteed that the folder `Documents` exists.